# Android WebView JavaScript callbacks fail in APK without Proguard

Tags: android, android-webview, proguard

I'm exposing `@JavascriptInterface` callbacks for a WebView which work just fine when debugging the app via Android Studio, however if the app is installed via APK the JavaScript callbacks fail with:

**"Uncaught TypeError: NativeApp.onProgress is not a function"**

I'm aware that improper Proguard rules can result in this problem, but in this case the project is not using Proguard and the problem occurs with debug and release APKS.

If I inspect the APKs, the methods are present.

```
public class MyServiceWithEmbeddedWebView {    
    ...

    public createWebview() {
    ...
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "NativeApp");
    ...
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    void onProgress(int loaded, int total) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the scope of the `@JavascriptInterface` methods to `public` solved the problem.

So this works for an APK install:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void onProgress(int loaded, int total) {
    // this is public
}
```

This does NOT work for an APK install, but works like a champ when deployed by the Android Studio debugger:

```
@JavascriptInterface
void onProgress(int loaded, int total) {
    // this is NOT public
}
```

How annoying!

Comment: I was stuck on this problem since 3 hours. Thank you very much brother