# WebView JavaScript Interface only seems to work through the Android Studio's Instant-Run, but not when compiled through regular gradle

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-instant-run

## The Setup

I have a simple fragment that hosts a WebView component. During the initialization of this fragment, I register a few JavaScript interface methods to my app:

```
mJavaScriptHooks = new JavaScriptHooks();
...
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mJavaScriptHooks, "Android");
```

My JavaScript hooks are nothing spectacular, and all are declared in the following manner:

```
public class JavaScriptHooks {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void someMethod() {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In order to make sure that these methods are not obfuscated or optimized away into oblivion, I've added the following the my [ProGuard configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629507/how-to-configure-proguard-for-javascript-interface):

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

## The Problem

**Everything works as expected.** The web page successfully invokes the methods through the provided "Android" object, the methods are called and perform their corresponding task. **However**, it only works when I run the app using the APK that was generated through the Android Studio's [Instant-Run](https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f#.fplg64q5p) feature.

It doesn't matter if the APK is installed through Android Studio or if I install it through the command-line using `adb install`

If I compile my APK through regular gradle (or if I disable Instant-Run), then the JavaScript interface stops working.

## Debugging

First off, I've ensured that **ProGuard** is **disabled**. Even if ProGuard was somehow ✨ magically ✨ enabled, my ProGuard configuration should ensure that my JS methods are left alone.

I've also disassembled the APK to **make sure** that the methods being exposed through the JS Interface have not somehow become mangled (or removed). They're not. They seem to be present, as declared, in the DEX file.

When I run the APK that was generated with Instant-Run enabled, I can inspect (through Chrome) that the page loaded in the WebView and see that my "Android" object is available and all the methods I've exposed are there (and invokable):

```
> Android
Object
    someMethod()
    __proto__
```

However, when I run the APK with Instant-Run disabled (i.e. vanilla gradle), the "Android" object is available, but none of my methods are there. It's just an empty object.

```
> Android
Object
    __proto__
```

The page I'm loading in WebView lives on a publicly-visible server that I control. The same page is loaded in both APK builds, and the methods are invoked in the same manner. Only the APK built with the Instant-Run feature seems to work.

I've been digging around all day, but I couldn't find anything really helpful. Most suggestions point to a ProGuard configuration problem or to old bugs (i.e Gingerbread-era) in WebView.

Comment: Whats your min Sdk?

Comment: How do you disable proguard? using minifyEnabled false in build.gradle?

Comment: @NageshSusarla, minimum SDK version is 19 (4.4). And yeah, minifyEnabled is false. ProGuard is disabled under buildTypes. I don't set proguardFiles for the debug type (which is what I'm targeting).

Comment: @MDV Dex isn't the final thing--on the device, the dex file is recompiled into another form (.oat). What I would try, is to make sure some non-dead code actually calls into the methods of the injected object.

Comment: @MikhailNaganov I tried that too. No difference unfortunately.

Comment: @MDV Is there anyway you can create a bug on b.android.com with the reproducer and link here? I can't seem to reproduce it as mentioned. (Please add Studio version to the bug)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, WebView can only recognize methods if installed by android studio with the SDK whose version is same as the device. after searching the internet, I found this:

[Android WebView JavaScript callbacks fail in APK without Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727497/android-webview-javascript-callbacks-fail-in-apk-without-proguard)

Have you declared your JavascriptInterface methods public? I saw your example method is public, but you are not showing the real code, maybe you forget this in your real code?